# clojure: spawn a process asyncronously

Tags: shell, clojure

With clojure.java.shell/sh it's possible to execute a shell command. After the invoked process is finished, the function returns a map containing it's exit code, std-out and std-err strings.

How can I capture stdout/-err of a spawned process from the moment it started? And: How can I terminate the process from within a clojure program/repl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible with `clojure.java.shell/sh`. You might take a look at [Raynes/conch](https://github.com/Raynes/conch) which provides [features you ask for](https://github.com/Raynes/conch#buffering) (getting output right after start etc.)

You can also DIY with [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and [`java.lang.Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) where you have full access to [process's input stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) or [a method to terminate it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy()).

Comment: looks like this is the only way right now. Still struggling with this API (conch). I don't get it working. Do you maybe have a minimal example - conch or java native?

Comment: [There are some tutorials covering `ProcessBuilder` and `Process` examples](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/processbuilder/java-lang-processbuilder-example/), including reading process std out from a separate thread. You can easily adapt it to Clojure.